# PHP how to form submit using ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying a simple ajax request that does not need to refresh the page upon submit. But I think I did it the wrong way. Any help would be much appreciated.

**HTML/JS PAGE**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('form#person').on('submit', function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'addAPerson.php',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (o) {
                          =====>    console.log(o); <=== I TRIED DOING THIS BUT NOTHING IS PRINTED
                    alert('MUST ALERT TO DETERMINE SUCCESS PAGE');
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });     
</script>

<form id="person" action="addAPerson.php" method="post">
  Firstname: <input name="fname" />
  Lastname: <input name="lname" />
  <input type="reset" style="float:right"name="cancel" value="cancel"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="save"/>
</form>
```

**addAPerson.php**

```
<?php
  $fname = $_POST['fname'];
  $lname =$_POST['lname'];
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysql_select_db("person",$con);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO person(firstname, lastname) VALUES('$fname', '$lname')";

  mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: For one thing, this `<input name="fname" />` needs to be changed to `<input type="text" name="fname" />` and do the same for the other one.

Comment: @Fred-ii- `type="text"` is the default.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, I didn't know that, till now. Thanks for the added info, will keep that in mind. (call it habit) ;-)

Comment: No idea if it is necessary, but a full path for the URL might be nice??

Comment: @Barmar Since the Ajax already contains `action="addAPerson.php"`, is it still necessary as the form action? I remember seeing many times, that it wasn't necessary to be inside the form, just the Ajax, as long as it point to the form's ID, am I correct?

Comment: @Fred-ii- The form action will be ignored, since the AJAX code contains `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: It is now submitting my form. But I still need to refresh the page to be able to see the submitted data. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have more than one form on the page, you need to change:

```
$('form').serialize(),
```

to:

```
$(this).serialize(),
```

Otherwise it will include fields from all the forms in the parameters to this script.

I'd also recommend that the PHP echo something to indicate whether it was successful or not, which the AJAX success function can then display.

You should also sanitize the inputs to the script, and convert from the mysql_xxx functions to mysqli_xxx or PDO, preferably using parametrized queries.

Comment: Thanks for this such a small mistake but.. My only problem is that my form was successfully submitted but the data is not there. I still need to refresh the page to see the inserted data. Any recommendation? Thanks

Comment: You need to put code in the `success` function that updates the DOM to show the new data. In traditional form submission that would happen because it reloads the page, but you need to code it explicitly when using AJAX.

Comment: I tried to use console.log() the 'o' but didn't print anything. Sorry, I'm still new in ajax request. Thanks for the help tho.

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry. I just edited my post. What should be done to be able to print my inserted data? Again, so glad for your help.

Comment: Have you read any AJAX tutorials? I'm not going to try to teach you how to do AJAX in this setting, the tutorials should show it.

Comment: Actually, it's not even AJAX-specific. Just use ordinary jQuery to update your page, with methods like `.html()` or `.append()` to add what you want in the appropriate place on the page. The only AJAX-specific thing is that you do it in the `success` function.

Comment: Yes. I checked my code again but I guess I'm missing a line or two. Thanks

Comment: There's nothing in `o` because the PHP doesn't echo anything.

Comment: I'm so glad that you helped me out. Very very much appreciated. Thanks again. It's now working.

Answer (score 0):

Following is my test based on your codes. I have a few modification in there. First, I put in jQuery link and add "type" to each textbox.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="./jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('form#person').on('submit', function(e) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'test.php',
                    data: $('form').serialize(),
                    success: function () {
                        alert('MUST ALERT TO DETERMINE SUCCESS PAGE');
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });     
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="person" method="post">
  Firstname: <input name="fname" type="text" />
  Lastname: <input name="lname" type="text" />
  <input type="reset" style="float:right"name="cancel" value="cancel"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="save" />
</form>
</body>
```

This is php code. Instead of wirting to database I simply echo a string. I can see the alert when I click "save" button without refreshing the page.

```
<?php echo "success"; ?>
```

Here is an alternative for your requirement. They provide source code which you can download and test run at local.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/